# Breaking foreach at certain string/ Reading through text file and generating XML

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I don't know if this is the right way to go about it, but right now I am dealing with a very large text file of membership details. It is really inconsistent though, but typically conforming to this format:

Name

School

Department

Address

Phone

Email

&&^ (indicating the end of the individual record)

What I want to do with this information is read through it, and then format it into XML.
So right now I have a `foreach` reading through the long file like this:

```
<?php 

$textline = file("asrlist.txt");

foreach($textline as $showline){
echo $showline . "<br>";
}


?>
```

And that's where I don't know how to continue. Can anybody give me some hints on how I could organize these records into XML?

Comment: Have you read about [SimpleXML](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) yet, or [DOMDocument](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) ?

Comment: And where do you need help - with parsing your fields & records, or with generating XML?

Comment: Parsing through the records. I'll check out those two out, but I was hoping I could do it with PHP and Javascript alone. If I could just have it insert <member> around each record I would probably be able handle the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a straightforward solution using `simplexml`:

```
$members = explode('&&^', $textline); // building array $members
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><members></members>");
$fieldnames = array('name','school','department','address','phone','email');

// set $fieldsep to character(s) that seperate fields from each other in your textfile
$fieldsep = '\p\n'; // a wild guess...

foreach ($members as $member) {
    $m = explode($fieldsep, $member); // build array $m; $m[0] would contain "name" etc.
    $xmlmember = $xml->addChild('member');        

    foreach ($m as $key => $data)
        $xmlmember->addChild($fieldnames[$key],$data);
} // foreach $members

$xml->asXML('mymembers.xml');
```

For reading and parsing the text-file, CSV-related functions could be a good alternative, as mentioned by other users.

Comment: This is a huge help, thank you. I'll spend some time dissecting it, but it sets me off in the right direction.

Comment: So now my problem is that PHP returns an error saying that the second argument in explode() has to be a string. Assuming that using file() is where I went wrong, I changed it to $textline = file_get_contents("asrlist.txt") instead. Now when I echo explode('&&^', $textline);, it just returns "Array".

Comment: @AustinSlominski: check if $textline really contains what you think it does by doing a `var_dump($textline)`.

Answer (score 1):

To read big files you can use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 1):

If `&&` works as a delimiter for records in that file, you could start with replacing it with `</member><member>`. Prepend whole file with `<member>` and append `</member>` at the end. You will have something XML alike.

**How to replace?**
You might find unix tools like [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) useful.

```
sed 's/&&/\<\/member\>\<member\>/' <input.txt >output.xml
```

You can also accomplish it with PHP, using `str_replace()`:

```
foreach($textline as $showline){
     echo str_replace( '&&', '</member><member>', $showline ) . "<br>";
}
```